# Mockito - Return Generic types ( multiple )

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

So basically I want to create a mockito unit test which returns a generic type and it's essential for me that I verify that method do return specific object-types. Any idea or tips on this would be helpful.

```
class Example {
    public AnotherClass<T> generateExampleType( String args ) {
         return new AnotherClass<T> (args);
    }
}

class Another {

     String method1(Type1 a) {
        //
     }

     String method2(Type2 a) {
        //
     }
}

class ClassUnderTest{


   public void methodUnderTest() {

    // code

      AnotherClass<Type1> obj1 = helper.<Type1>generateExampleType("abc");
      AnotherClass<Type2> obj2 = helper.<Type2>generateExampleType("def");

      String one = another.method2(obj2);
      String two = another.method1(obj1); // this fails as part of verify in unit test

    // code
   }
}
```

Test

```
when(helper.<Type1>generateExampleType(anyString()).thenReturn(Obj1Mock);
when(helper.<Type2>generateExampleType(anyString()).thenReturn(Obj2Mock);
verify(another).method2(Obj2Mock);
verify(another).method1(Obj1Mock); // This fails expected Obj1, actually passed Obj2
```

Both Obj1 and Obj2 are used as part of other method invocation in the same workflow. However, mockito always defaults to the last created(obj2 in this instance) and my unit tests fail

```
/*
 Expected class - Type1
 Actually invoked - Type2
*/
```

Comment: Why do you want to return a generic type?

Comment: The `generateExampleType` method doesn't have a type parameter.

Comment: @Tim - I want to return a generic, it's part of a huge workflow

Comment: @Bubletan it returns a specific type and I do require that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution which was required. This should solve the issue and it did for me :-

http://www.agilearts.nl/tasty-test-tip-using-argumentcaptor-for-generic-collections-with-mockito/